# Intel xdk toggle

Tags: javascript, html, intel-xdk

apologies in advance for the newbie question but my javascript knowledges are very low yet. I am developing with intel xdk and I would like to show a given field if the toggle is toggled, otherwise hide it. Here is my code

```
<li class="item item-toggle widget uib_w_66 d-margins" data-uib="ionic/toggle" data-ver="0" id="addbang_bangtoggle">Bang?
                    <label class="toggle toggle-assertive">
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <div class="track">
                            <div class="handle"></div>
                        </div>
                    </label>
                </li>
```

Any idea on how this could be handled?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are using ionic designer. The functionality of toggle here is more like a check box that you find in smartphones UI.

For what you want to do perhaps the ACCORDION control in Framework7 is suitable.
Here is a link to a detailed post.
http://hodentekmobile.blogspot.com/2016/10/intel-xdk-controls-13-accordion-control.html